# Xamarin Android JNI ERROR accessed deleted Global 0x000000

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, java-native-interface

I am having a uncatchable error like below.
Where should I start to debug this kind of error?

I guess this is a memory leak issue or referencing deleted object by GC.
However, error message does not give me any clue why this is happening or where should I start to dig in...

You can check out [vimeo](https://vimeo.com/548710444)

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed deleted Global 0x606a
[java_vm_ext.cc] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted global reference 0x606a
[java_vm_ext.cc] "Thread-28" prio=10 tid=34 Runnable
[java_vm_ext.cc]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x13080000 self=0x7ac5a58c00
[java_vm_ext.cc]   | sysTid=8181 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7aaabfd4f0
[java_vm_ext.cc]   | state=R schedstat=( 237903034 19270156 585 ) utm=20 stm=3 core=3 HZ=100
[java_vm_ext.cc]   | stack=0x7aaa9fe000-0x7aaaa00000 stackSize=2MB
[java_vm_ext.cc]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
[java_vm_ext.cc]   native: #00 pc 00000000003cb654  /system/lib64/libart.so 

// ...

[libc] Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 8181 (GLThread 25), pid 7983 (ngoslab.lithium)
```

Here is full [error log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UCMnSU0z1zfG3nshuyOuPULX5Qp5wueG/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason. When invalidate two `SKGLView` simultaneously, I face `JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed deleted Global 0x606a`.

So, I change from `SKGLView` to `SKCanvasView`. After that, issue never showed up.